# Apply formula (processing) to Range before passing to another formula

Tags: vba, excel, substitution, textjoin

I am trying to apply `TEXTJOIN` formula in one of the cells.
But the problem occurred when I needed to pre-process each cell in the range.
For example the data is something as below.

`╔══════╦══════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Test ║     Rest     ║ Extras1 ║ Extras2 ║ Extras3 ║
╠══════╬══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║      ║ English-test ║ corner  ║         ║         ║
║      ║ Chinese-test ║ corner  ║ view    ║         ║
║      ║ Korean-test  ║ corner  ║ room    ║ room_2  ║
╚══════╩══════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝`

In the Test column, I was seeking to Join the text in Rest after Substituting the word -test to each word in Extras. What I expect is the following.

`╔═════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║                  Test                   ║     Rest     ║ Extras1 ║ Extras2 ║ Extras3 ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ English-corner                          ║ English-test ║ corner  ║         ║         ║
║ Chinese-corner|Chinese-view             ║ Chinese-test ║ corner  ║ view    ║         ║
║ Korean-corner|Korean-room|Korean-room_2 ║ Korean-test  ║ corner  ║ room    ║ room_2  ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝`

The basic formula I have used is `TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Extras1:Extras3)`, however I want something like `TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(Rest,"-test",Extras1:Extras3))` if possible. Replave "-test" in Rest column with values from range, resulting in range.

Tried VBA as well, but I couldnt find anything that would process Range before inputing in function.
Manual process works but takes longer time.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a good solution to be done with a User-defined function in VBA:

```
Public Function someTest(firstVal As String, ParamArray otherVal() As Variant) As String

    Dim someVal As Variant
    Dim delim As String:    delim = "|"
    Dim splitVal As String: splitVal = "-"

    For Each someVal In otherVal
        someTest = someTest & Split(firstVal, splitVal)(0) & delim & someVal
    Next someVal

End Function
```

And this is how you call it:

[image]

The function uses `ParamArray()` and it loops through every element of it, concatenating with the first part of the first parameter. Thus, from `English-test` only `English` is taken.

---

With a small change it is possible to pass the second argument as a range. Thus, it will be a bit easier:

```
Public Function someTest2(firstVal As String, otherVal As Range) As String

    Dim someVal As Range
    Dim delim As String:    delim = "|"
    Dim splitVal As String: splitVal = "-"

    For Each someVal In otherVal
        someTest2 = someTest2 & Split(firstVal, splitVal)(0) & delim & someVal
    Next someVal

End Function
```

[image]

Here the second parameter is given as a range. Every range has at least one cell, thus the function loops through the cells.

Comment: This helps but doesn't completely solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a formula; less extensible than a UDF:

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Rest,"test",Extras1&"|",1),"test",Extras2&"|",1),"test",Extras3&"|",1),"|","",COUNTA(Extras1:Extras3))